# How to find all comments in the source code?

Tags: java, comments

There are two style of comments , C-style and C++ style, how to recognize them?

```
/* comments */

// comments
```

I am feel free to use any methods and 3rd-libraries.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? What do you want to do with the comments, once you found them? What do you mean by "recognizing" them?

Comment: The following is a valid comment inside a `.java` source file: `\u002f\u002a multi line comment \u002A/`. Note that `\u002f == '/'` and `\u002a == '*'`. Do you want to account for those too?

Comment: only valid comments inside java

Comment: @user705414, the example I gave _is_ a valid comment inside Java.

Comment: @Bart, I don't really care about unicode form of comments.

Comment: @user705414, your remarks: _"I don't really care about unicode form of comments"_ and _"only valid comments inside java"_ are contradicting. If you don't care for the corner cases, then _"only valid comments inside java"_ is not true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To reliably find all comments in a Java source file, I wouldn't use regex, but a real lexer (aka tokenizer).

Two popular choices for Java are:

- JFlex: http://jflex.de
- ANTLR: http://www.antlr.org

Contrary to popular belief, ANTLR can also be used to create *only* a lexer without the parser.

Here's a quick ANTLR demo. You need the following files in the same directory:

- [antlr-3.2.jar](http://antlr.org/download/antlr-3.2.jar)
- JavaCommentLexer.g (the grammar)
- Main.java
- Test.java (a valid (!) java source file with exotic comments)

### JavaCommentLexer.g

```
lexer grammar JavaCommentLexer;

options {
  filter=true;
}

SingleLineComment
  :  FSlash FSlash ~('\r' | '\n')*
  ;

MultiLineComment
  :  FSlash Star .* Star FSlash
  ;

StringLiteral
  :  DQuote
     ( (EscapedDQuote)=> EscapedDQuote
     | (EscapedBSlash)=> EscapedBSlash
     | Octal
     | Unicode
     | ~('\\' | '"' | '\r' | '\n')
     )*
     DQuote {skip();}
  ;

CharLiteral
  :  SQuote
     ( (EscapedSQuote)=> EscapedSQuote
     | (EscapedBSlash)=> EscapedBSlash
     | Octal
     | Unicode
     | ~('\\' | '\'' | '\r' | '\n')
     )
     SQuote {skip();}
  ;

fragment EscapedDQuote
  :  BSlash DQuote
  ;

fragment EscapedSQuote
  :  BSlash SQuote
  ;

fragment EscapedBSlash
  :  BSlash BSlash
  ;

fragment FSlash
  :  '/' | '\\' ('u002f' | 'u002F')
  ;

fragment Star
  :  '*' | '\\' ('u002a' | 'u002A')
  ;

fragment BSlash
  :  '\\' ('u005c' | 'u005C')?
  ;

fragment DQuote
  :  '"' 
  |  '\\u0022'
  ;

fragment SQuote
  :  '\'' 
  |  '\\u0027'
  ;

fragment Unicode
  :  '\\u' Hex Hex Hex Hex
  ;

fragment Octal
  :  '\\' ('0'..'3' Oct Oct | Oct Oct | Oct)
  ;

fragment Hex
  :  '0'..'9' | 'a'..'f' | 'A'..'F'
  ;

fragment Oct
  :  '0'..'7'
  ;
```

### Main.java

```
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JavaCommentLexer lexer = new JavaCommentLexer(new ANTLRFileStream("Test.java"));
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
      for(Object o : tokens.getTokens()) {
      CommonToken t = (CommonToken)o;
      if(t.getType() == JavaCommentLexer.SingleLineComment) {
        System.out.println("SingleLineComment :: " + t.getText().replace("\n", "\\n"));
      }
      if(t.getType() == JavaCommentLexer.MultiLineComment) {
        System.out.println("MultiLineComment  :: " + t.getText().replace("\n", "\\n"));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Test.java

```
\u002f\u002a <- multi line comment start
multi
line
comment // not a single line comment
\u002A/
public class Test {

  // single line "not a string"

  String s = "\u005C" \242 not // a comment \\\" \u002f \u005C\u005C \u0022;
  /*
  regular multi line comment
  */
  char c = \u0027"'; // the " is not the start of a string

  char q1 = '\u005c'';                  // == '\''
  char q2 = '\u005c\u0027';             // == '\''
  char q3 = \u0027\u005c\u0027\u0027;   // == '\''
  char c4 = '\047';

  String t = "/*";
  \u002f\u002f another single line comment
  String u = "*/";
}
```

Now, to run the demo, do:

```
bart@hades:~/Programming/ANTLR/Demos/JavaComment$ java -cp antlr-3.2.jar org.antlr.Tool JavaCommentLexer.g
bart@hades:~/Programming/ANTLR/Demos/JavaComment$ javac -cp antlr-3.2.jar *.java
bart@hades:~/Programming/ANTLR/Demos/JavaComment$ java -cp .:antlr-3.2.jar Main
```

and you'll see the following being printed to the console:

```
MultiLineComment  :: \u002f\u002a <- multi line comment start\nmulti\nline\ncomment // not a single line comment\n\u002A/
SingleLineComment :: // single line "not a string"
SingleLineComment :: // a comment \\\" \u002f \u005C\u005C \u0022;
MultiLineComment  :: /*\n  regular multi line comment\n  */
SingleLineComment :: // the " is not the start of a string
SingleLineComment :: // == '\''
SingleLineComment :: // == '\''
SingleLineComment :: // == '\''
SingleLineComment :: \u002f\u002f another single line comment
```

### EDIT

You can create a sort of lexer with regex yourself, of course. The following demo does not handle Unicode literals inside source files, however:

### Test2.java

```
/* <- multi line comment start
multi
line
comment // not a single line comment
*/
public class Test2 {

  // single line "not a string"

  String s = "\" \242 not // a comment \\\" ";
  /*
  regular multi line comment
  */
  char c = '"'; // the " is not the start of a string

  char q1 = '\'';                  // == '\''
  char c4 = '\047';

  String t = "/*";
  // another single line comment
  String u = "*/";
}
```

### Main2.java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Main2 {

  private static String read(File file) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
    while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
      String line = scan.nextLine();
      b.append(line).append('\n');
    }
    return b.toString();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String contents = read(new File("Test2.java"));

    String slComment = "//[^\r\n]*";
    String mlComment = "/\\*[\\s\\S]*?\\*/";
    String strLit = "\"(?:\\\\.|[^\\\\\"\r\n])*\"";
    String chLit = "'(?:\\\\.|[^\\\\'\r\n])+'";
    String any = "[\\s\\S]";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
        String.format("(%s)|(%s)|%s|%s|%s", slComment, mlComment, strLit, chLit, any)
    );

    Matcher m = p.matcher(contents);

    while(m.find()) {
      String hit = m.group();
      if(m.group(1) != null) {
        System.out.println("SingleLine :: " + hit.replace("\n", "\\n"));
      }
      if(m.group(2) != null) {
        System.out.println("MultiLine  :: " + hit.replace("\n", "\\n"));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you run `Main2`, the following is printed to the console:

```
MultiLine  :: /* <- multi line comment start\nmulti\nline\ncomment // not a single line comment\n*/
SingleLine :: // single line "not a string"
MultiLine  :: /*\n  regular multi line comment\n  */
SingleLine :: // the " is not the start of a string
SingleLine :: // == '\''
SingleLine :: // another single line comment
```

Comment: Beautiful  solution. However if I don't care edge cases like unicode and comment characters inside string, can I use regular expression?

Comment: That you don't care for the exotic Unicode literals, I can imagine. But I don't understand ignoring what is inside string literals. If you want to forget all of that, sure, go ahead and use regex, but you're then ignoring your requirement _"only valid comments inside java"_ completely. A regex solution is likely to choke on `String s = "//";` and `String s = "/*";` (at least, the regex solutions posted sofar).

Comment: URL to ANTLR.org has a typo. Should be http://www.antlr.org. I tried editing but I was blocked due to minimum number of characters required for an edit not satisfied.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** I've been searching for a while, but here is the **real** working regex:

```
String regex = "((//[^\n\r]*)|(/\\*(.+?)\\*/))"; // New Regex
List<String> comments = new ArrayList<String>();

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(code);
// code is the C-Style code, in which you want to serach
while (m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    comments.add(m.group(1));
}
```

With this input:

```
import Blah;
//Comment one//
line();
/* Blah */
line2(); // something weird
/* Multiline
another line for the comment
*/
```

It generates this output:

```
//Comment one//
/* Blah */
line2(); // something weird
/* Multiline
another line for the comment
*/
```

Notice that the last three lines of the output are one single print.

Comment: This fails, just as Tomasz's suggestion. Add `String s = "foo /* bar";` (a string literal) or even `\u002f\u002a multi line comment \u002A/` (a **valid** comment) in the source.

Comment: Also, the `Pattern.MULTILINE` is not needed, and you might want to include `\r` in the class `[^\n]` (although most line breaks end with `\n`... But still, old Mac files may end their lines with just a `\r`).

Comment: @Martjin, nice solution. However, line2(); itself is not the comment. How to remove it?

Comment: Hehe, it's funny looking back at this: regex is not meant to operate on non-regular languages. Only if I knew some more theory back then 

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried regular expressions? [Here](http://ostermiller.org/findcomment.html) is a nice wrap-up with Java example. <strike>It might need some tweaking</strike> However using only regular expressions won't be sufficient for more complicated structures (nested comments, "*comments*" in strings) but it is a nice start.

Comment: "Some" tweaking is a bit of an understatement, IMO. Have a look at the last paragraph ("Caveats") to see when it fails.

Comment: Thanks, I failed to read *Caveats* carefully. Corrected my answer.