# how to find multiline comments from a java file?

Tags: java, string, file, comments, lexical-analysis

I've read my java source file and stored it's contents in String s
However i'm facing difficulty in finding the multiline comments from file

My task is to find the multiline comments like these:-

```
/* i am helpful
i am great
*/
```

and display them

Comment: Try with regular expressions.

Comment: PacoAbato can u please tell me what kind of rex?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640071/how-to-find-all-comments-in-the-source-code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you could use regular expression with Pattern and Matcher classes.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?s)/\\*.*?\\*/");
```

`(?s)` DOTALL modifier which makes the dot in the regex to match also the line breaks.

**Example:**

```
String s = "foo/* i am helpful\n" + 
        "i am great\n" + 
        "*/"
        + "bar";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?s)/\\*.*?\\*/");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while(m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

**Output:**

```
/* i am helpful
i am great
*/
```

Comment: What about if the `/*` or `*/` characters are part of a `String` literal; that is, they're inside double quotes?  In that case, they're not multi-line comment delimiters, and you don't want your expression to find them.  For a correct solution to this problem, regular expressions are not the right tool.

Comment: yep, i agree with that. regex is not the right tool for this . He needs to use a parser for more complex cases.