# How to find the commented code in IntelliJ IDE?

Tags: intellij-idea, shortcut

Does anyone know a way to search for all (and only) the commented code across all classes in a java project?
For example, using "Find in Path" to search for "//" is not what I want because it also returns URIs (http://......). I want a specialized way to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find all comments in the source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640071/how-to-find-all-comments-in-the-source-code)

Answer (score 5):

You can use Structural Search in IntelliJ IDEA.

Below screens as for the version **2019.1.1** (Ultimate Edition) (Works for IntelliJ IDEA **2020.3** too)

Go to **Edit > Find > Search Structurally...**

[image: Structural Search window]

File type should be Java and select any path wherever you like to search.

From the top right corner click on gear icon and click on **Existing Templates...**

[image: Existing Templates window]

Then from **Java > Comments, Javadoc and Metadata** select **comments**

Then it will add `/* $CommentContent$ */` to the Structural Search window as for the first screenshot.

This will find all the commented code (including Javadoc) from the selected path.

For more info refer : [Structural search and replace](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace.html)

Answer (score 2):

As of intellij 2020.3, there is an inspection for commented out code in java:

Java | Code maturity | Commented out code
[image]

So if you want a list of commented out code, you can:

1. right+click your project, module, subfolder, directory or file where you want to search.
2. click analyze > inspect code
3. Click OK

This should open the inspection result window where all your commented out code will be grouped under Java | Code maturity | Commented out code :

[image]

If you don't want intellij to search for other issues too, you can create a new profile in File | Settings | Editor | Inspections exactly for that and select it in the analyze dialog.

Answer (score 0):

About the best you could do would be the Find In Path and use a REGEX of:
^//

That will fix your http:// problem.  But it won't find comments that don't start at the beginning of a line.  I suppose you could write a much more complex REGEX to find "//" but not proceeded by http:  But of course comments can be in /* */ blocks too.  So it all depends on how absolute you want to get.

Comment: Thank you but this only partially solves my problem. I am looking more for a "tool" or windows that would display the commented lines (or the one that contain comments at the end). Something similar to the "TODO" .